# Is it safe to paste secure notes into Notepad if you clear your clipboard?

Tags: windows, password-management

Password manager software such as LastPass and Keepass often offer some form of a secure note feature, which allows the user to encrypt data with their master password. However, their GUIs may not be good for side-by-side work, and I may want to paste the secure note into another window for easier work.

For example, if I have my PHP configuration passwords stored in Lastpass as a secure note, I want to be able to execute these commands on an SSH shell, and repeatedly alt-tabbing between the browser vault window (with a very small text box) is annoying if I wish to perform this action repeatedly.

Does Notepad save any form of data on disk that can be later retrieved by attackers that would result in exposure of the secure note, even if the clipboard was cleared?

Comment: Also related http://security.stackexchange.com/q/33428/86652

Comment: unlike fancy editors, notepad.exe does not save anything without being told to do so. One possible exception would be hibernating, but you can't blame notepad for that...